# Website's url when tracking multiple subdomains in Google Analytics under one account

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I would like to track a main domain in Google Analytics and also its multiple subdomains. But I would like each domain to have its profile, to be able to view every subdomain separately.

I made an account GA and its property. Then I made a profile for the main domain and created a rule to add domain name to the results:

> 1. In the Profile Settings page, click the Add Filter link.
> 2. Choose Add New Filter and provide the filter a name.
> 3. Choose Custom Filter and select Advanced on the Filter type settings.
> 4. Under Advanced settings:
>          FieldA should be set to Hostname
>          FieldB should be set to Request URI
> 5. Set the values for both Field A and Field B to (.*), which is an expression that captures all characters.
> 6. Set the Output To --> Constructor option to Request URI and provide $A1$B1 as the value for that choice.
>
> Your reports will now show:
>
> - www.example.com/index.php
> - sub.example.com/more.php

It's tracking code is:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Then I created another profile for the subdomain, where I set **the same** tracking code and also **the same website's URL** (`http://www.domain.com`) for every subdomain. Is this the right way to do so?

I also added a rule for all subdomains to **include** hostname:

```
givensubdomain\.domain\.com
```

Is it ok? I'm asking because I can see some online visitors in real time reports for both domains and subdomains, but I'm unable to see those when I look into the standart reports and set the date for today.

Comment: That question is about cross-domain tracking. This one is not.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18050/one-multi-domain-analytics-profile-or-one-analytics-profiles-per-domain covered in Jeff's answer I believe near the bottom.